# Error: package was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled

Tags: r, package, installation

I encountered a package installing problem, where I have absolutely no clue how to manage the situation.

```
install.packages("C:/Users/Oliver/Downloads/NPRED.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Oliver/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘NPRED’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
library("NPRED", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.5")
```

*

```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘NPRED’:
>      package ‘NPRED’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
```

*

Can anyone help me out on that problem??

Highly appreciated!
cheers,
olli

Comment: 3.5 changed some of the internals.  Since you're installing a binary package you need to have downloaded a version of the package that was built using at least 3.5

Comment: is there any way i can bypass that?
downloading 3.4 for instance?

Comment: @Dason;downgrading to 3.4 and the package runs successfully

Comment: If the package was previously installed before you upgraded to 3.5+  you need to completely uninstall it and then reinstall, you can't just do a normal update of the package.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Find the currently installed packages, put this in a data frame
df_all_packages <- as.data.frame(installed.packages())
```

Have a look at this, to check which major and minor R versions are there.

```
View(df_all_packages)
table(df_all_packages$Built) # how many packages built under each version of R
```

The example below assumes you use R 4 and want to upgrade some packages based on R 3.6. You should adjust this to your own case.

```
# Find older package versions, make a list with packages which are of older version and you want to update
df_packages_to_upgrade <- as.data.frame(subset(df_all_packages, (Built %in% c('3.6.1', '3.6.2','3.6.3'))))
# Or you can prefer to base the filtering on those you want to keep, if so uncomment next line:
# df_packages_to_upgrade <- as.data.frame(subset(df_all_packages, !(Built %in% c('4.0.1', '4.0.2','4.0.3'))))

# Finally re-install the packages :
install.packages(df_packages_to_upgrade$Package)
```

Sometimes, the above will fail. There might be changes on dependencies for a specific package, which may be hard to track; this could involve tricky OS-level dependencies. In one case, I had to do:

```
# At bash command line, as root:
yum install jq-devel protobuf-devel libcurl-devel openssl-devel geos-devel gdal gdal-devel proj-devel proj-nad proj-epsg libjpeg-turbo*
# use 'apt-get install' on Debian-based
# Then, in R (as linux super-user), remove all old packages - but before, make a copy-paste of the list, just in case
# The list:
old_packages_removed <- rownames(df_packages_to_upgrade)

remove.packages(df_packages_to_upgrade$Package)
# Then I installed the 2 or 3 packages I really needed, which ended up installing 50 packages (most of the previously un-installed ones)
# You could try, instead:
install.packages(old_packages_removed)
```

This solved the issue for me.