# Custom Packaged Installed with different internals

Tags: r, install.packages

I have the zip file of a package written by a colleague that has since left the firm.  Upon installation with the latest version of R I get this message

```
library(xxx)
'package ‘xxx’ was installed by an R version with different internals'
```

The installation command did not return an error

```
install.packages("xxx.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
package ‘xxx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

Is there a way that I can update the package (rewrite?/recompile?) to work with the latest version of R?  Please note that its an INTERNAL package and I only have access to the zip file.

I have seen this but there doesn't seem to a satisfactory answer

[Error: package was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144957/error-package-was-installed-by-an-r-version-with-different-internals-it-needs)

Comment: If it is an internal package, you should have access to the source code (if not, something went seriously wrong in your company). You need to build the binary from that source code. Otherwise, you'll have to install an outdated R version and keep using that.

Comment: You could also try recreating the source code from the installed package, but this would require some work. The first step would be to dump all functions from the package namespace.

Comment: tks for the prompt response.  guess i should start by tracking down the author ...